# How do I edit a text field in Selenium 2?

Tags: junit, selenium-webdriver

I can type text into a field using `WebElement.sendKeys()` but editing doesn't work: I can neither move the cursor nor delete the last character that I typed with `e.sendKeys( Keys.BACK_SPACE )`

How do I modify the value of a text field in Selenium 2 (WebDriver)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can definitely do that by either of the two methods. I have tried and it works.

```
e.click()   # Positions the cursor at the end of the string
e.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE )
```

Or you could simply clear the text, and start over again:

```
e.clear()
e.sendKeys("What you want to send")
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution that seems to work pretty well. It basically clicks on the text field WebElement, then sends Ctrl-End to put the cursor at the end of the text. Then sends the string that I had previously initialized.

(quickReplyTextArea is a text field WebElement that I have previous found, as is postQuickReplyButton (button instead of text field, obviously). replyText is a String that I initialized earlier)

```
    quickReplyTextArea.click();
    quickReplyTextArea.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.END));
    quickReplyTextArea.sendKeys(replyText);
    postQuickReplyButton.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try clicking first into that text box, and use sendKeys() afterwards.

Comment: Has no effect, either. This makes sense since I send the keys directly to the `WebElement` (and not to the page/browser/parent element).